# No option to Add user in AWS IAM Identity center

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

In the new version of AWS IAM Identity center there is no option to add user, I'm using Google as external identity provider and don't want to use python sdk for it.

Tried to add user for SSO.
Expected: ADD USER button

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the Users section.